# How to Integrate hadoop cluster with application server?

Tags: hadoop, integration, hbase, backend

I have various application servers (Ex. web application) and I also have been playing with hadoop with Hbase, Impala, Hive etc. I can get results that I am looking for using command line or using web interface such as Hue.

Now how does one integrate Hadoop as backend with current application replacing backend solutions such as MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle etc.?

p.s I know many are batch processing with hadoop but HBase does give some near real-time analytics. Even if its batch processing, I want to give the users to start some analytics and come back and view the results in my own frontend application.

Comment: Did it figure it out how to achieve this. I am also stuck here. I know how each tools work. But I'm searching way to interface them from a web app (php/java).

Answer (score 2):

Each of the framework provides multiple interfaces and it's own API which are not compatible with each other. Take a look at [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) which makes it easy to work with multiple databases (RDBMS and NoSQL). Here ([1](http://www.packtpub.com/spring-data/book), [2](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024767.do)) are some books on Spring Data.

I had not been following Spring Data, so not sure how active is the community around it. Maybe someone can add to this.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern with many variations involves using a Hadoop workflow executed over and over on newly ingested data (or a Storm topology or just a Kafka consumer) to process the data and cache it in a NoSQL DB.  You could use something like Cassandra or HBase if you want to store the result with a finer granularity or elasticsearch or mongoDB if you want a coarser-grained result.  Then, when a request comes into your web API layer, your logic there can pull the latest, necessary data out of the cache DB, optionally transform it into the correct format, apply any last minute calculations and return the data to the client as a JSON object.

Comment: can you elaborate on what solutions are available that will allow me to interface with HBase/Impala/Hive from web API layer such as in Php or Perl etc. I saw something about Thrift but is there any generic middle layer which will allow to talk to multiple technologies?